# Is there a global JS / TS file that is loaded on server side and on client side in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm looking for a global JS / TS file that is loaded before other files are loaded.

One on the server side and one on the client size.

Let's say before the page files are loaded.

Does a global file like this exist?

Comment: Svelte itself has no server. Are you using SvelteKit?

Comment: @brunnerh Yes I am. I mean, for `page.server.ts` for example

Comment: Maybe you are looking for https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks ?

Comment: @Corrl Looks interesting, I'll look into it probably today

Comment: @Corrl It worked, if you add an answer, I'll accept it.